# Data sorting and update of UIcollectionViewCells. Is this a lost cause?

Tags: ios, core-data, ios6, uicollectionview

I have core data entries displayed in a collectionView, sorted from 1 2 3 ... n. New batches of entries are added as the user flips through the first n. Data is built from a JSON response  obtained from a web server.

Because the first entry of the fetch request is associated to cell 0 - via the datasource delegate -, it's not possible to add a new batch at the bottom of the collection view. If it's added from cell 0, old cell contents are replaced by new ones, or in short the whole page seems to be replaced by new stuff, and the data the user was looking at is offset by the number of new entry.  If the batch is large, it's simply buried. Furthermore, if the update is done from cell 0, all entries are made visible, which takes time and memory.
There are several options that I considered:

1) data-redorder, meaning instead of getting the fetch result as 1 2 3 4 ... n, I need the opposite, n ... 3 2 1 (nothing to do with a fetch using reverse order sorting) straight from the fetch request. I'm not sure it's possible? is there a CD gotcha allowing to re-order the fetch result before it is presented to the UICollectionViewDataSource delegate ?

2)Change the Index path/viewCell association in "collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:", Use (numberOfItemsInSection - IndexPath.Item). It creates several edges cases, as entries can be removed/updated in the view (hence numberOfItemsInSection changes). So I'd rather avoid it if I can...

3) adding new data from cell 0, ruled out for the reason I explained. There may be a solution: has anyone achieved a satisfactory result by setting a view offset? For example, if 20 new entries are added, then the content of cell 0 is moved to cell 20. So, we just need to tell the view controller to display from cell 20 onwards. Any image flipping or side effects I might expect?

4) download a big chunk of the data, and simply using the built-in core data faulting mechanism. But that's below optimal, because I'm not sure exactly how much I should download - user dependent - and the initial request (JSON+Core Data) might take too long. That's why lazy fetching is here for anyway.

Any advice someone facing the same problem could share ?

Thanks !

Comment: I don't understand why you can't add the new batch at the bottom of the collection view. What's the problem with that? Can't you just add the new data to the end of the array that populates your collection view cells?

Comment: data isn't fetched via an array, it's extracted using [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]. Whenever I download a new batch of data, it is inserted into CD, then assigned to the CView via a fetched request. In the fetched result, new entries appear first, and are assigned automatically to viewCells from 0 onwards. Because of the way UICollectionViewDataSource works, cell indexes and fetched entries follow the request sorting order. Hence, it is impossible to add new ones at the bottom, because that's were the last ones are displayed. How did you solve this problem?